# I can't Edit/Add New Post in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I've tried everything:

1. Deactivate plugins and reactivate one by one
2. Configure .htaccess
3. Change Permalink
4. Re-install Wordpress

The issue is in the theme I guess. Whenever I changed mine to default, it works, but not with the current one.

I am using Averie Theme: [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuJl0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved! The issue is in the theme. I just upgraded the theme to latest version

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the theme to like Twenty seventeen etc.. and see if the issue is still remains. as Jovan Jovanović said, it can be related to your theme.